# Installing Tomcat 5.5 from source for PHP Java Bridge

Tags: apt, software-installation, java, php, tomcat

I want to install PHP/Java Bridge. I installed Tomcat 7 for it, but it failed:

```
sudo dpkg -i /home/asif/jbridge/php-java-bridge-j2ee_5.4.4.2-3_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package php-java-bridge-j2ee.
(Reading database ... 190386 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking php-java-bridge-j2ee (from .../php-java-bridge-j2ee_5.4.4.2-3_all.deb) ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/tomcat5.5 not found.
dpkg: error processing /home/asif/jbridge/php-java-bridge-j2ee_5.4.4.2-3_all.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 100
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/tomcat5.5 not found.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/asif/jbridge/php-java-bridge-j2ee_5.4.4.2-3_all.deb
```

See it says: `/etc/init.d/tomcat5.5 not found.` So I want to install Tomcat5.5 but Jakarta is no longer active. So I got Tomcat5.5 from [Apache archives](http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-5/v5.5.12/src/). I have downloaded [apache-tomcat-5.5.12-src.zip](http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/tomcat-5/v5.5.12/src/apache-tomcat-5.5.12-src.zip) and now I don't know how to install it. How can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried installing as well. It worked on Tomcat7. You can try that...